# RegEx to match m: ss for input validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been struggling to create a RegEx to fulfill the following:

- only one number for the minutes (0 to 9);
- only two numbers for the seconds (00 to 59);
- must have the format *m:ss*.

So far I have this: `^(?:([0]{0}?\d):)?([0-5]{1}?\d)$`

However the case *00* for example seems to be passing and it shouldn't, since it's not in the *m:ss* format.

Comment: What did you intend to match with `[0]{0}?`?

Comment: `/(\d\:\d\d)/` try this?

Comment: @Jai that regex wouldn't match the 3 points I mentioned.

Comment: @user3632710 people already answered below so i didn't updated my comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your regex - [`^(?:([0]{0}?\d):)?([0-5]{1}?\d)$`](https://regex101.com/r/mP6hK6/2) - has a `0{0}?` that makes the engine match `0` exactly zero times (this token is ignored). It also has redundant `{1}` (as `[0-5]` will match a digit from `0` to `5` exactly one time). Note that there is no reason to place a single character into a character class (like `[0]`), it might cause issues later when you need to adjust the pattern. *And more importantly*, your regex contains an *optional* group `(?:([0]{0}?\d):)?` that can match one or zero times. Thus, your regex allows input like `56`.

You can use the following regex:

```
/^\d:[0-5]\d$/
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mP6hK6/3)

```js
var rx = /^\d:[0-5]\d$/;
var tests = ['0:00','1:34','156','3:67','45:55','56','4:344'];

for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += tests[i] + ": " + (rx.test(tests[i])) + "<br/>";
}
```

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"/>
<input type="text" pattern="\d:[0-5]\d" /><br/>
```

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d` - one digit
- `:` - a colon
- `[0-5]` - one digit from `0` to `5` range
- `\d` - one digit
- `$` - end of string

Comment: I added a demo to both your regex and my suggestion. Feel free to test out and see the difference.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, since it's javascriot, it's much better IMHO to give a snippet, instead of a 3rd party link

Comment: I added a demo of the strings I used in regex101.com. Thank you, @Tushar.

Answer (score 6):

Unless I am missing something this should be very simple...

```
^[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$
```

```js
var regex = /^[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/;
var input = $('input');
input.keyup(function() {
  if (regex.test(input.val()))
    input.removeClass('error');
  else
    input.addClass('error');
});
```

```css
input.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input/>
```

---

[Here is a working example](https://regex101.com/r/iN9sV4/2), which provides a full explanation:

> **^** assert position at start of a line
>
> **[0-9]** match a single character present in the list below 0-9 a single
>   character in the range between 0 and 9
>
> **:** matches the character : literally
>
> **[0-5]** match a single character present in the list below 0-5 a single
>   character in the range between 0 and 5
>
> **[0-9]** match a single character present in the list below 0-9 a single
>   character in the range between 0 and 9
>
> **$** assert position at end of a line

Comment: @musefan, since it's javascript, it's much better IMHO to give a snippet, instead of a 3rd party link

Comment: @musefan, one definite adventage of them is that they're inhouse in SO, so they won't get lost with time, 3rd party links can get deleted

Comment: @Gavriel: Yeah I get that, but in this case it's just supporting the answer. There doesn't really need to be anything more that just the regex to make the answer useful. I have added one anyway

Answer (score 3):

the regex is: `/^\d:[0-5]\d$/`

```js
["2:12", // OK
 // the rest are invalid:
 "2:60","09:12", "13:2", "123:1", "123:23", "123:456"].forEach(function(s){
  if (s.match(/^\d:[0-5]\d$/)) {
    alert(s);
  }
});
```

Only "2.12" will be alerted, the rest are invlaid,